# Android - Calling Activity into Fragments - Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, drawer

I've downloaded the sample project from the Android official site http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html. I am trying to understand how the Navigation Drawer works. So, I have one doubt, they call a Fragment for each item from the left menu. In my project, I have a big activity which I am trying to call by this Fragment:

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(getActivity(), ListMatch.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_match, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

But, if I do that, it calls perfectly my Activity, but the menu disappear. How can I call this activity and keep my menu? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you need to have the drawer of the activity also. Or have a BaseActivity with the drawer and the other activity extend from BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

Like Raghunandan said, the drawer applies wihin a single activity. It's common to launch a new activity from the "main" drawer, but usually that kind of activity would have the up action set in the action bar to go back to the main activity.